# JQuery validate doesn't work in Mozilla Firefox, but works in IE

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, jquery-validate

I have the following .jsp page which works completely when I'm using the eclipse browser (which is essentially IE), but it doesn't register at all in firefox:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
    });
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy" );

    $().ready(function() {
        $("#commentForm").validate({
            rules: {
                ime: "required",
                prezime: "required",
                datepicker: {
                    minlength: 10, 
                    dateISO: true
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
table.tablesorter {
    width: 80%;
}
</style>
```

And the following table:

```
<table class="tablesorter">
    <tr><th colspan="2"><c:out value="${naslov}"/></th></tr>`
    <form action="ClanPostaveServlet" id="commentForm" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <tr>
    <td>Ime*:</td>
                <td><input id="ime" type="text" name="ime" value="${clanPostave.ime}" size="40"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prezime*:</td>
                <td><input id="prezime" type="text" name="prezime" value="${clanPostave.prezime}" size="40"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mesto rođenja:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="mestoRodjenja" value="${clanPostave.mestoRodjenja}" size="40"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Datum rođenja:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datumRodjenja" value="${clanPostave.datumRodjenja}" maxlength="10" size="10"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Biografija:</td>
                <td><textarea name="biografija" rows="3" cols="29"><c:out value="${clanPostave.biografija}"/></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="${mode}"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="entity" value="${entity}"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="naslov" value="${naslov}"/>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Sačuvaj"/></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
```

Now, this works in IE. Before, I had the attributes in each input field, rather than between the script tags in the header. I had `<input id="prezime" type="text" name="prezime" value="${clanPostave.prezime}" size="40" required/>` and that also worked, in IE.

I'm just learning jQuery, so I could be missing something trivial. Any additional info (apart from the answer) will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$().ready(function()` this is useless here

Comment: What happens when you try to run the page through the W3C online HTML Validator?